# Querying rows with coupled conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got an SQLite table where I store user settings with the following schema :

```
CREATE TABLE settings (
  [id] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  [token] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  [value] varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  [created] datetime NOT NULL,
  [user_id] INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The name of the setting is `[token]`.
The value of the setting is `[value]`.

I'd like to **SELECT users who have 2 specific settings (both)** :

- *english speaking users* (`[token]='language' AND [value]='en'`),
- *subscribed to the newsletter* (`[token]='newsletter' AND [value]='1'`),

So I tried :

```
SELECT user_id FROM settings 
WHERE  
        (token = 'language' AND value = 'en')
    OR  (token = 'newsletter' AND value = 1) 
)
GROUP BY user_id
```

But it doesn't work as I get users which ONLY have one of the 2 conditions (**I want both**).
How can I do?

Comment: On a sidenote: Is `value` a string or a number now? One time you compare it to `'en'`, one time to `1`. Be consistent. Compare with `'1'` (which also illustrates that you won't get a match on `'01'` for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Simply aggregate your table per `user_id` and use `HAVING` to ensure both conditions are met for the user.

```
select user_id
from settings
group by user_id
having count(case when token = 'language' and value = 'en' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when token = 'newsletter' AND value = 1 then 1 end) > 0
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to speed this up, if you like:

```
where (token = 'language' and value = 'en') or (token = 'newsletter' AND value = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try This query :

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM settings 
WHERE  (token = 'language' AND value = 'en')
        OR  (token = 'newsletter' AND value = '1')
```

There is no use of Group By clause

Comment: Ok, I tried and I also get users than don't have the token "language" defined and I want it defined to 'en'.

Comment: By removing the `GROUP BY` clause, you get exactly the same user_ids of course only multifold.